# ORA-00936 (missing expression) when groovy script attempts to select

Tags: oracle, groovy

So I've seen a bunch of threads about this SQL error but I'm not seeing a solution to this particular situation. The long story short is that I have a message processing server that executes some scripts on payloads before passing the payload on. These scripts are in groovy, and I'm getting an error in my log as follows:

```
WARNING groovy.sql.Sql [process-1{channel}] - 
  Failed to execute: 
    select column
      from table
        where field1 = ?
          and field2 in ([468001])
   because: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

That's the log file. When I actually print out the string created by groovy it's the following:

```
select column
  from table
    where field1 = 2.5249083E7
      and field2 in (groovy.sql.Sql$35@f7326f4e)
```

I assume the scientific notation is just the way groovy prints that type, and the expand creates an object that doesn't get printed very well.

The actual groovy code that creates this error is

```
sql.eachRow("""
  select column
    from table
      where field1 = $var1
        and field2 in (${Sql.expand(varList2.join(','))})
""") { row ->
```

The part that's throwing me is that this exact code within this script executes fine in a different point in a different groovy script. It's literally copy and pasted (though I didn't write it and this is one of my few groovy experiences, so that doesn't mean much). If anyone has any tips that would be awesome.

I would be more than happy to have someone tell me I'm an idiot and why. It's such a simple error that I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious. I've renamed the variables and table/column names but I can assure you those are correctly spelled and copy/pasting the filled in version returns data.

Comment: What's `varList2` in the query that works, and what is it here?

Comment: Same in both. It's a list, but it only contains one thing (an integer, generally about 6 digits). It's an issue with our data model. Originally we thought it would contain more than one thing, but we ended up just doing one-to-one instead of one-to-many in the table setup. Hence the list that never has more than one item.

Comment: Does it still fail with `and field2 = ${varList2.take(1)}`

Comment: Good question. I'll give that a shot and see what happens. (Server takes quite a long time to build and start up, so this might take awhile.)

Comment: The problem, from the log, is the square brackets that are being put around the value. You need to look at why `${Sql.expand(varList2.join(','))}` ends up as `[468001]` instead of just `468001`. In other places the same pattern works, are you changing a setting that alters the expansion behaviour, perhaps? Or are those part of the `varList2` value before the join/expand? If you still have the same problem with `=`, can you bind it instead?

Comment: Not that I know of, but the server isn't really my project 90% of the time so that doesn't mean much. It's someone else's baby. I'll see what happens if I just have it say = variable instead of in (variable list). Rebuilding the ejs now.

Comment: Alex nailed it (and Tim as well, but I was too dumb to really check). Despite the fact that the data type for the contents of varList2 is "long", for some reason it's an array. So varList2 is an array of arrays and that's what's blowing it up. Thanks for the help, now I just need to find out why groovy is turning a long into an arraylist. Somewhere in the train between java and groovy it's converting it without being asked.

Comment: The method Sql.expand is convenient and suggest to be secure. But it should be noted that it is potential enabler of **SQL Injection**.  Which can be demonstrated with `varList2 = ['468001) or (1=1']` providing access to the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was diagnosed by @tim_yates and @Alex.
Anyway I'd suggest to use a different approach to bind the IN LIST (the same approach used by Hibernate).

```
 groovyCon.eachRow 
    ('select * from mytab where x in (' + varList2.collect{'?'}.join(',') + ')',varList2) 
      {println it}
```

This leads a s SQL string

```
 select * from mytab where x in (?,?)
```

which is not only SQL Injection proof, but also more effective as queries with the same cardinality of the IN LIST may be reused without hard parse.

Additionally, while trying to pass wrong data types you get exception:

```
 Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
```